# What will be the impact of not applying 'await' keyword before async call in C#

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous, async-await

I have a code block as below

```
public async Task GeneratePE(string ackLevel, string messagingProtocol)
{
    Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Message msg = await this.FormMessage(ackLevel);
    Trace.WriteLine($"D2C message send start time: {DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")}");
    this.InitializeDeviceClient(messagingProtocol);
    this.deviceClient.SendEventAsync(msg);         
    await this.ReceiveC2dAsync(3, "create", "abc", "protocol");
}
```

In the `this.deviceClient.SendEventAsync(msg)` line await is not given. What I do here is I am sending a message by that line and in the next line `this.ReceiveC2dAsync(3, "create", "abc", "protocol")` I look to receive it from another place.

My test is working fine with the above code snippet. But it fails intermittently as well waiting to receive the message. Anyway failure is random.

Comment: Well `ReceiveC2dAsync` may execute before `SendEventAsync` has completed. Is there a reason why you have omitted `await` for `SendEventAsync`? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You're basically turning that call into an "async void", with all the bad consequences it has.

Comment: @Johnathan Barclay I am not sure on the exact reason, but it works like that way only. After sending the event I immediately I need to receive it by 'ReceiveC2dAsync()'. Ideally I should be start listening before I send the message, but that's not working fine in my code snippet

Comment: What is the error exactly? If you need to run `ReceiveC2dAsync` before `SendEventAsync` is complete. you could hold a reference to the `Task` returned by `SendEventAsync` then await it after `ReceiveC2dAsync`.

Comment: @Johnathan Barclay It's not specific error message but the execution times out and did not proceed further after out of "ReceiveC2dAsync" if I move that before "SendEventAsync". Can you please explain how to hold reference and then await.

Comment: `Task task = this.deviceClient.SendEventAsync(msg);         
await this.ReceiveC2dAsync(3, "create", "abc", "protocol");
await task;` or alternatively: `await Task.WhenAll(new Task[] { this.deviceClient.SendEventAsync(msg), this.ReceiveC2dAsync(3, "create", "abc", "protocol") });`. The latter will allow both to execute simultaneously and wait for them both to complete.

Comment: @Johnathan Barclay Thanks. Will try that way